# Security website check links and pass to destination

Tags: security, hyperlink

I have a web application, there is one input can let user post their website links.

However I try to protect user as I can.

Is any free website can check the links for you?

What i'm looking for is passing the links to the security site, if the links is ok, it will auto pass to the destination, if not, it will stop and let user know the site is not safe.

links(my site) -> security check website -> destination

Comment: Define "ok" or "not safe" in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Web of Trust API](http://www.mywot.com/en/api) allows you to check the user-provided "reputation" of a website.

Answer (score 1):

WOT is a good suggestion. However, keep in mind that the crowdsoured nature of this project can be an issue, security wise.
For example, using few fake account, one can boost the trust of a malicious domain. This is especially true for "under the radar" domains, that would generate no organic ratings.

Admittedly, this would probably be resolved over time (as users become exposed to the threat) but the process could be repeated again and again...

I would suggest to use WOT as cross reference, combining it with other factors (i.e. Alexa) just to filter out small domains, which are not likely to be rated - expect by their owners.

Best way is to manage your own list...